# returning html file with django after user input

Tags: python, django

I have some HTML tables which I extract from a third party program which I'd like to show without using a javascript.

The user gets to see 4 categories and each category has multiple options. From each category only 1 item can be selected.

For instance:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html

This site takes information from a database, but what I want to do is, is to filter for a specific HTML table. Since i have like 2800 tables I want a quick way to filter for it.

Using:
Checkmarks, and a slider for percentages from 0% to 100% that defines a range.

now I'd like to receive the input and link them to an html table which I have stored. I have tried linking my javascript to it, but it will only load images and not an HTML table.

So to be more clear. User inputs his position in the game. I.e. EP, MP, CO, HJ. Then he puts in how many points he has: 10, 15, 20, 25. Then he again puts in a frequency 0%-100% and based on what he picks I want him to send that information and that should match my HTML file which is static. I.e. EP_10_50percent.html should be loaded if he chooses EP, 10 points and 50 percent frequency.

What's my course of action? Thank you so much

Comment: What's the point of those html files? I think you require just "redirecting"

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py define, checkout this link  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example

```
urlpatterns = [
path('some_view/<int:score_1>/<int:score_2>', views.myview) 
]
```

In your views

```
def myview(request, score_1, score_2):
    if score_1 == 10 and score_2==50:
      return render(request, f"app/EP_{score_1}_{score_2}.html")
    elif ...:
      ...
```

In your template.(Make it appropriate)

```
<a href="/10/50"></a>
```

This will submit 10 and 50 to your view and then by comparing the values send back a `render(...)`

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I get that part, but where does my user input / choose the variables? So to be more clear. User inputs his position in the game. I.e. EP, MP, CO, HJ. Then he puts in how many points he has: 10, 15, 20, 25. Then he again puts in a frequency 0%-100% and based on what he picks I want him to send that information and that should match my HTML file which is static. I.e. EP_10_50percent.html should be loaded if he chooses EP, 10 points and 50 percent frequency. Thanks again